# how to get deterministic playback of video segment with safari html5 video player?

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video

Deterministic segment video playback:

1. set `currentTime` on the videoPlayer to desired start
2. `addEventListener` function for the `timeupdate` event
3. call videoPlayer.play()
4. pause playback when the event listener detects that `currentTime` exceeds the desired end time.

This strategy works reliably in chrome and FireFox.
It fails intermittently in Safari, both macos and ios.

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
         <style>
            button {
             font-size: 24px;
             }
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="movieDiv" style="margin-left: 40px;">
        <video id="videoPlayer"  controls height="400" preload="auto">
            <source src="https://slexildata.artsrn.ualberta.ca/tlingit/37AtlinSrprizLk.mov">
        </video>
      </div id="movieDiv">
    
      <div id="buttonDiv" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <br><button onclick="playVideoSegment(58, 62)"> mov 58-62</button>
      </div id="buttonDiv">
    
    <script>
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    var videoSegmentEnd;
    var videoContinuousPlay = true;
    
    videoPlayer.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
       console.log("video can now play");
       })
    
    videoPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function (){
        console.log(videoPlayer.currentTime)
        if (!videoContinuousPlay && videoSegmentEnd && videoPlayer.currentTime >= videoSegmentEnd){
          videoPlayer.pause();
          videoContinuousPlay = true;   
          }   
        }, false);
    
    function playVideoSegment(startTime, endTime){
        videoContinuousPlay = false;
        videoSegmentEnd = endTime;
        videoPlayer.pause()
        videoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        videoPlayer.currentTime = startTime;
        videoPlayer.play();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can you suggest how to code around this inconsistency?
Minimal demo [here](https://slexildata.artsrn.ualberta.ca/tlingit/tinyTimingBug.html).
The non-determistic symptom you will see in any Safari browser:  the button requests video+audio playback from 58 seconds to 62. Sometimes that works, other times quite imperfectly.